# WPF DataGrid perform action on multiple selected rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF that contains a list of names and email addresses, and an event handler that performs an action when a row is double-clicked:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Emails" ItemsSource="{Binding AddressBook}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGrid_Emails_RowDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Path=Email}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'd like to be able to extend this functionality to work on multiple rows if multiple rows are selected. Is it possible for me to simply add somethins to my EventSetter to cover this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can add anything to this because you can doubleclick only one row at a time. But you can get the Selected Rows in your handler and apply your action to them. For that In your handler you can use **SelectedItems** property of DataGrid.

Comment: Thanks! I might have worded my question a little vaguely, but I was able to get it to work using SelectedItems. I just bound my action to the Enter key instead :)